# GWT Editor: select calls twice before update

Tags: gwt, editor

During update the entity with Editor framework select from db calls twice. 
May be it's not a problem but a feature of Editor framework?

Here is a code snippet:

```
public class UserActivity extends BasicActivity<UserActivity.Display> {

...

interface Driver extends RequestFactoryEditorDriver<UserProxy, UserPanel> {
}

private UserProxy user;

private Driver driver;

@Inject
private Provider<UserRequestContext> userContextProvider;

...

@Inject
public UserActivity(EventBus eventBus, Display display, PlaceController placeController, WmsRequestFactory requestFactory) {

    super(display, eventBus, placeController);

    driver = GWT.create(Driver.class);
    driver.initialize(requestFactory, (UserPanel) display);

}

...

@Override
protected void onBind() {

    UserRequestContext userRequestContext = userContextProvider.get();

    userRequestContext.updateUser(user);

    driver.edit(user, userRequestContext);

    registerHandler(display.getSaveButton().addClickHandler(
            new ClickHandler() {
                public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {

                    RequestContext context = driver.flush();

                    // Check for errors
                    if (driver.hasErrors()) {
                        display.getStatus().setHTML(
                                "<b>Errors detected locally</b>");
                        return;
                    }

                    // Send the request
                    context.fire();

                }
            }));

   ...
```

Hibernate output after save button clicked:

```
 [INFO] Hibernate: select user0_.ID as ID1_0_, user0_.CREATED as CREATED1_0_, user0_.MODIFIED as MODIFIED1_0_, user0_.version as version1_0_, user0_.BIRTH_DATE
as BIRTH5_1_0_, user0_.EMAIL as EMAIL1_0_, user0_.FIRST_NAME as FIRST7_1_0_, user0_.LAST_NAME as LAST8_1_0_, user0_.LOGIN as LOGIN1_0_, user0_.PASSWORD as PASS
WORD1_0_ from USER user0_ where user0_.ID=?

[INFO] Hibernate: select user0_.ID as ID1_0_, user0_.CREATED as CREATED1_0_, user0_.MODIFIED as MODIFIED1_0_, user0_.version as version1_0_, user0_.BIRTH_DATE
as BIRTH5_1_0_, user0_.EMAIL as EMAIL1_0_, user0_.FIRST_NAME as FIRST7_1_0_, user0_.LAST_NAME as LAST8_1_0_, user0_.LOGIN as LOGIN1_0_, user0_.PASSWORD as PASS
WORD1_0_ from USER user0_ where user0_.ID=?

[INFO] Hibernate: update USER set MODIFIED=?, version=?, BIRTH_DATE=?, EMAIL=?, FIRST_NAME=?, LAST_NAME=?, LOGIN=?, PASSWORD=? where ID=? and version=?
```

Is it normal?

Answer (score 0):

Answered on the GWT Google Group: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-web-toolkit/T4N1puddcS4/vV1wYZ6n9EUJ

Copied here for reference and convenience:

First, this has nothing to do with the Editor framework, but with RequestFactory.

If you're not using a `Locator`, or you're not overriding the `isLive()` method of your `Locator`, then this is the expected behavior: this is how RequestFactory determines whether an entity is still "alive" before sending the response to the client. If it's not, then it'll tell the client that the entity has been deleted (dispatch an `EntityProxyChange` event on the EventBus with a `WriteOperation.DELETED`). The default implementation of `isLive(entity)` is `find(entity.get()) != null`, and this is also what happens in the absence of a `Locator` for an entity (the difference is that with a `Locator` you can override isLive() to change the default implementation with, e.g., a more optimized one).